# JSON Invalid Why?

Tags: json, extjs

I generated this JSON but it s not valid for sencha's proxy, i don't understand why?

> { "text" : ".", "children":[
>
> {task:'Reporting - Version-3',
>   material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31872',
>   children : [
>
> {task:'500    MIGRATION ET PRA',
>   material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31879',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'200  Mise en œuvre
>   du réseau', material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31884',
>   children : [
>
> {task:'Identification du propriétaire
>   du process', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31889', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Dossier d'architecture source',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31892', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Choix des prestataires
>   (FT, etc..)', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31895', leaf : true}, {task:'Plan
>   de développement', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31898', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Réception des OLA/SLA',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31901', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Identification du
>   périmètre', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31904', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Rédaction du plan d'adressage
>   de prod, pré prod, admin , backup',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31907', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Volumétrie et matrice
>   des flux', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31910', leaf : true}, {task:'Etude
>   des configurations Switchs, routeurs,
>   firewall', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31913', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Validation du PASe NANTERRE et
>   CLICHY', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31916', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Données en entrée',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31919', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Identification du schema
>   d'implantation source',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31922', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Identification du
>   paramétrage des alteons',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31925', leaf :
>   true}]}, {task:'300   Intégration de la
>   Production', material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31928',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'400  Intégration
>   de la PP et DEV', material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31933',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'600  Sécurité',
>   material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31940',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'100  Pilotage du
>   projet de transformation',
>   material:'', cc:'',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31947',
>   children : [
>
> {task:'add_2', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31952', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Approvisionnement',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31955', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'aa', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31958', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Management des ressources
>   humaines', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'2011/02/09', id:'31961',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'Réunions',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31966', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'T0 du projet',
>   material:'sw_testing_hour',
>   cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'2011/02/02', id:'31969',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'Planning projet',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'2011/02/06', id:'31974',
>   leaf : true}, {task:'Rappel des
>   contraintes', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31979', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Management Financier',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31982', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Management des
>   partenaires', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31985', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Management du risque et des
>   problèmes',
>   material:'sw_testing_hour',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31988', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Réunion de lancement MSO',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31991', leaf :
>   true}, {task:'Definition des droupes
>   de travails', material:'default',
>   cc:'programme 1', start_date:'',
>   id:'31994', leaf : true},
>   {task:'Réunion de lancement client',
>   material:'default', cc:'programme 1',
>   start_date:'', id:'31997', leaf :
>   true}]}]}]}

Comment: I have found my answer ! :)
the double quote it's important always !

Thank to : http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tool I use to vaidate JSON: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com According to it you should have your strings wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all try tools like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to
beautify your JSON.

Then you can inspect further.

BTW: I what language are you programming? Most high level languages provide decent means to generate JSON on the fly from objects of that language.

Comment: I have no experience with TCL but it seems that there are some libs out there that can achieve this for you ie. http://lehenbauer.github.com/yajl-tcl/

Answer (score 0):

Your json names need to have double quotes surrounding them.  I would start there and then check to see if there are any more errors